# Jodit tool bar - how can I make it "left-aligned"?

Tags: javascript, jodit

I have a s-d issue with Jodit (which I much like!). The two leftmost standard toolbar buttons "grow" with a large screen, and thus cause the toolbar to occupy the whole space above the text area (align=even, kind of). [image: Screen shot].

The text area is in div which is again wrapped within another div with "d-flex". Perhaps someone has come across this?